# The Expectation of the Product of two Stochastic Integrals

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Suppose $ M, N\in \mathcal{H}^{2,c} $, $K \in L^2(M)$ and $ F \in L^2(N)$. Show that for each $ t \in [0,\infty]$ we have

$$  \mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[ \left(  \int_{0}^{t}K_{s}dM_{s}\right ) \left( \int_{0}^{t}F_{s}dN_{s}\right ) \right] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}} \left[   \int_{0}^{t}K_{s}F_{s}d\langle M,N \rangle_{s} \right] $$

I have struggled with this for a while! Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

$$\left(  \int_{0}^{t}K_{s}dM_{s}\right ) \left( \int_{0}^{t}F_{s}dN_{s}\right ) - \bigg \langle  \int_{0}^{\cdot}K_{s}dM_{s}, \int_{0}^{\cdot}F_{s}dN_{s}\bigg \rangle_t$$
is a martingale and hence 
$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\left(  \int_{0}^{t}K_{s}dM_{s}\right ) \left( \int_{0}^{t}F_{s}dN_{s}\right ) \bigg] = \mathbb{E}\bigg[\bigg \langle  \int_{0}^{\cdot}K_{s}dM_{s}, \int_{0}^{\cdot}F_{s}dN_{s}\bigg \rangle_t \bigg] = \mathbb{E} \bigg[\int_0^t K_s F_s d \langle M,N \rangle_s \bigg]$$
with the last inequality following by the defining property of the Ito integral with respect to the quadratic variation.

---

Seeing that the first expression is indeed a martingale is a standard exercise (and a good one to make sure you understand well so I'll try to be detailed here).

Note first that an Ito integral against an element of $\mathcal{H}^{2,c}$ is again an element of $\mathcal{H}^{2,c}$ so that 
$$\bigg\{\int_0^t K_s dM_s, \int_0^t F_s dN_s \bigg\} \subset\mathcal{H}^{2,c}$$

It follows from Doob's Maximal inequality that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\bigg[ \sup_{t \geq 0} \bigg|\int_0^t K_s dM_s \int_0^t F_s dN_s \bigg| \bigg] \leq& \mathbb{E}\bigg[ \sup_{t \geq 0} \bigg(\int_0^t K_s dM_s \bigg)^2 \bigg]^{\frac12} \mathbb{E}\bigg[ \sup_{t \geq 0} \bigg(\int_0^t F_s dN_s \bigg)^2 \bigg]^{\frac12}
\\ \leq& 4 \sup_{t \geq 0} \mathbb{E}\bigg[ \bigg(\int_0^t K_s dM_s \bigg)^2 \bigg]^{\frac12} \sup_{t \geq 0}\mathbb{E}\bigg[ \bigg(\int_0^t F_s dN_s \bigg)^2 \bigg]^{\frac12}
\\ <& \infty
\end{align}
and so $\sup_{t \geq 0} \bigg|\int_0^t K_s dM_s \int_0^t F_s dN_s \bigg| \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$. Also $\bigg \langle \int_0^\cdot K_s dM_s, \int_0^\cdot F_s dN_s \bigg \rangle_\infty \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$ and so the continuous local martingale 
$$L_t = \left(  \int_{0}^{t}K_{s}dM_{s}\right ) \left( \int_{0}^{t}F_{s}dN_{s}\right ) - \bigg \langle  \int_{0}^{\cdot}K_{s}dM_{s}, \int_{0}^{\cdot}F_{s}dN_{s}\bigg \rangle_t$$
satisfies $|L_t| \leq \sup_{t \geq 0} \bigg|\int_0^t K_s dM_s \int_0^t F_s dN_s \bigg| + \bigg \langle \int_0^\cdot K_s dM_s, \int_0^\cdot F_s dN_s \bigg \rangle_\infty \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$ for all times $t$ (and hence also at stopping times) since the quadratic variation is increasing. This implies that $L_t$ is a true martingale, since if $L_t^{\tau_n}$ is a martingale for each $n$ and $\tau_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ then we can now use the D.C.T. to pass to the limit $n \to \infty$ in 
$$\mathbb{E}[L_t^{\tau_n} \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = L_s^{\tau_n}$$ to conclude.

This is an example of a general fact; if $M,N \in \mathcal{H}^2$ then $MN - \langle M,N \rangle$ is a uniformly integrable martingale. The proof of this goes exactly as the special case above.

Comment: Thanks Rhys! How do we know that the above is a Martingale and not just a continuous local martingale?

Comment: I've made a detailed edit that hopefully explains this. I hope its clear now!

Comment: I don't understand why this answer hasn't been accepted

Comment: @RScrlli It's an unfortunate feature of this site that many users leave questions with decent answers inactive without comment. Unless I miss something about my answer, I guess this is just one of those cases. I don't care much about the reputation but it would be nice to have questions that receive answers marked as such for people who are browsing the site.

Comment: Indeed! I was searching for an easy proof for this particular result and this explanation was very good! Though one does not care about reputation is sad one one spends time answering smthng and it remains in the limbo